# Java calling one servlet from two sources

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm making a Java web-application with an user profile.
I have a profileServlet which is responsible for rendering two pages: profile.jsp and editProfile.jsp
The first source, from which profileServlet is being called, is a menu link on top of the page, and look like this:
    `<a href="profileServlet?param=profile">Profile</a>`

The second source is a "Edit" button in the profile.jsp:
 `<form name="editProfile" method="GET" action="profileServlet?param=editProf"><input type="submit" value="Edit"></form>`

Now in profileServlet, depending on the param value I want to make redirect either to profile.jsp or editProfile.jsp. Here is the code:
 `if(request.getParameter("param").equals("profile")) {
      response.sendRedirect("profile.jsp");
  } else if (request.getParameter("param").equals("editProf")) {
      response.sendRedirect("editProfile.jsp");
 }`

But I keep getting java.lang.NullPointerException.
Could you help please?

Stacktrace:

```
24.04.2014 11:44:30 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [profilePage.profileServlet] in context with path [/LinkedIn] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at profilePage.profileServlet.doGet(profileServlet.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you provide stacktrace?

Comment: @qazerty23 post your full stack trace here.

Comment: Just a second please.

Comment: @qazerty23 profileServlet.java:126 is this line if(request.getParameter("param").equals("profile"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request parameter `param` is probably null, you can either do it like below, or have proper null checking in place before using your variables

```
if ("profile".equals(request.getParameter("param")) {
    response.sendRedirect("profile.jsp");
} else if ("editProf".equals(request.getParameter("param")) {
    response.sendRedirect("editProfile.jsp");
}
```

Additionally, ensure that the code is place in their respective `doGet`/`doPost` handlers, or have one handler for both.

**Example:**

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    handleGetAndPost(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    handleGetAndPost(request, response);
}

private void handleGetAndPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
   if ("profile".equals(request.getParameter("param")) {
       response.sendRedirect("profile.jsp");
   } else if ("editProf".equals(request.getParameter("param")) {
       response.sendRedirect("editProfile.jsp");
   } 
}
```

Comment: After aplying this code, I stoped to get error, and redirection to profile.jsp works fine. However, when I try to call editProfile.jsp, I just get 1. @epoch

Comment: Does it also make sense to avoid the query parameter "param" in the form action attribute and rather make it a hidden form input?

Comment: @Shiraaz.M, in terms of maintainability that would be a better option, yes, but it makes no difference

Comment: Still getting just 1 :( @epoch What could cause this?

Comment: It finally worked when I changed the method in `<form name="editProfile" method="GET" action="profileServlet?param=editProf"><input type="submit" value="Edit"></form>` from GET to POST. Thanks @epoch

Answer (score 0):

you should use a post request when submitting a form, and have two different handler methods.
GET returns the empty form, and POST processes the submitted form.

Answer (score -1):

Better add null checks. Looks like you are not able to get `param`

```
    if (request.getParameter("param") != null && request.getParameter("param").equals("profile")) {
        response.sendRedirect("profile.jsp");
    } else if (request.getParameter("param") != null && request.getParameter("param").equals("editProf")) {
        response.sendRedirect("editProfile.jsp");
    }
```

Comment: @Aniket Thakur Wat this request != null request object will never be null

Comment: Yeah apologies. Typed in hurry. Add null checks for `request.getParameter("param")`. Edited the answer.